# How to differentiate the function $f(\mathbf x) = \|\mathbf x\|^2 \mathbf x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, jacobian

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be given by the equation $f(\mathbf x)=\|\mathbf x\|^2 \mathbf x$. Show that $f$ is of class $C^\infty$ and that $f$ carries the unit ball $B(\mathbf 0;1)$ onto itself in a one-to-one fashion. Show, however, that the inverse function is not differentiable at $\mathbf 0$.

How does one differentiate a function involving the Euclidean norm? It's simple enough if it was just the norm itself, but multiplied by a vector I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You could consider $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ and then $f(x) = (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ and then attempt to show that it is of class $\mathcal{C}^\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

If $f_1(x) = \|x\|^2$, then 
$f_1(x+h) = f_1(x)+ 2 x^T h + \|h\|^2$, so $Df_1(x)(h) = 2 x^T h$.

If $f_2(x) = x$, then $f_2(x) = f_2(x)+ h$, so $D f_2(x)(h) = h$.

The product rule gives
$D (f_1 \cdot f_2) (x) (h) = Df_1(x)(h) f_2(x)+ f_1(x) D f_2(x)(h)$, so we have
$D (f_1 \cdot f_2) (x) (h) = 2 x^T h x + \|x\|^2h = (2 x x^T + \|x\|^2I) h$.

Comment: Ok,I think this is correct,but makes it WAY more complicated then is necessary.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 What could be simpler than a single application of the product rule?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: I think this is more straightforward than component-wise differentiation. Plus, I think it shows the structure more clearly?

Comment: @copper.hat what componentwise differentiation? The components are polynomials

Comment: @zhw.: What polynomials? I was referring to computing the derivative ${\partial f_i(x) \over \partial x_j}$.

Comment: The problem was to show $f \in C^\infty.$ (btw, sorry, I thought this was timely but it's from 2014)

Comment: @zhw.: I read the problem as how to differentiate functions involving $x \mapsto \|x\|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** To make things easier for you, let's work on $n=2$ as always...

$f(x) = f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{pmatrix} (x_1^2+x_2^2)x_1 \\ (x_1^2+x_2^2)x_2 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be defined by

$$f (\mathrm x) := \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 \, \mathrm x = (\mathrm x^\top \mathrm x) \, \mathrm x$$

Hence,

$$\begin{array}{rl} \mathrm d f &= (\mathrm d \mathrm x^\top \mathrm x) \, \mathrm x + (\mathrm x^\top \mathrm d \mathrm x) \, \mathrm x + (\mathrm x^\top \mathrm x) \, \mathrm d \mathrm x\\\\ &= (\mathrm x \mathrm x^\top) \, \mathrm d \mathrm x + (\mathrm x \mathrm x^\top) \, \mathrm d \mathrm x + \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 \, \mathrm d \mathrm x\\\\ &= (2 \, \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top + \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 \, \mathrm I_n) \, \mathrm d \mathrm x\end{array}$$

Thus, the Jacobian matrix of $f$ is

$$\nabla f (\mathrm x) = 2 \, \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top + \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 \, \mathrm I_n$$