# Stuck on Jacobian matrix of $xx'Ax$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, jacobian

Let the $x$'s be vectors and $A$ be a matrix

\begin{align}
\nabla xx'Ax &= \partial(xx')Ax + xx'\partial(Ax)\\
&= \partial(xx')Ax + xx'A\textbf{1} \tag{i} \\
&= \partial xx'Ax + x\partial x'Ax + xx'A\\
&= \textbf{1}x'Ax + x\partial x'Ax + xx'A \tag{ii} \\
\end{align}

Questions:

**1)** Does $A1$ become $A$?

**2)** Is the $1$ (identity matrix) necessary? I tried inputting the following into [matrixcalculus.org](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/)  and they left the identity in there even though it's not present for other equations I put in?

```
(y * x' * A * x), with regards to y
x vector, y vector, A matrix
```

**3)** What rules or properties would I apply to do $x\partial x'Ax$?

---

Thanks for taking the time to read this far! I know my notation is sloppy and if you have any comments please let me know

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084095/339790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let vector field $\mathrm f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be defined by

$$\mathrm f (\mathrm x) := \left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x \right) \mathrm x$$

Hence,

$$\begin{aligned} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathrm f (\mathrm x + h \mathrm v) - \mathrm f (\mathrm x)}{h} &= \big( \left( \mathrm v^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x \right) \mathrm x + \left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm v \right) \mathrm x + \left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x \right) \mathrm v \big)\\ &= \big( \mathrm x \, \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A^\top + \mathrm x \,\mathrm x^\top \mathrm A  + \left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x \right) \mathrm I_n \big) \mathrm v\\ &= \big( \color{blue}{\mathrm x \, \mathrm x^\top \left( \mathrm A^\top + \mathrm A \right) + \left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x \right) \mathrm I_n} \big) \mathrm v\end{aligned}$$

where the expression in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ gives us the **Jacobian** of $\rm f$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that equation is the same as the equation I originally posted. Can you show the manipulation to get to it?

Comment: @user162264 $$\left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x \right) \mathrm x = \mathrm x \left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x \right)$$

Comment: Hmm a few questions: 0) OH, you can do that because you know $x^TAx$ is a scalar, right? Therefore it doesn't matter if you pre-multiply or post-multiply the x? 1)You extracted the v from the middle term (second line) by applying the same principle as above, right? $x^TAv$ is a scalar, then you move the post-multiplication to pre-multiplication then pull out the v? 2) The identity matrix that appears in the last term is because $x^TAx$ is a scalar, right? In general is this rule true? Do I always check the dimensions and leave the identity if the dimensions won't work out?

Comment: @user162264 The answer to all question is: yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming

1. $\nabla = \partial = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$
2. $x' = x^{T}$
3. Numerator layout

Then

> **(i)** Does A1 become A?

Yes it does, you can see that in the next line.

> **(ii)** Is the 1 (identity matrix) necessary?

Yes it is, since $x'Ax$ is a scalar, hence $Ix'Ax$ is the matrix with $x'Ax$ in every diagonal entry and zeroes everywhere else.

> **(iii)** What rules or properties would I apply to do
>   $$x∂x′Ax$$?

$\partial x' = \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}$  is an operator that transposes the next column vector into a row vector. You can see this doing

$$\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}v = \frac{\partial x'v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v'x}{\partial x} = v'\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = v'$$

The case when $v=Ax$ is a little bit more complicated, but you can check that it works as well.
$$\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}Ax = (Ax)'$$

Hence $x\partial x'Ax = x(Ax)' = xx'A'$ and your final expression is $Ix'Ax + xx'(A'+A)$

Comment: (ii) So you're multiplying by 1 to make the dimensions work out, right? Why the identity vs the 1-matrix of appropriate size? In programming languages I think they multiply by a matrix of 1s

Comment: It's not an arbitrary choice, that's what comes out of the calculation, since $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = I$